# Search feature for sites on stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, search, stackexchange.com

I went to [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites) to see if a specific site existed. But with 101 sites it takes quite a while to manually scan them all, and hope you don't miss any one of them.

Could we get a search box on [this page](https://stackexchange.com/sites) so that we could search for the specific sites we're looking for?

Comment: Just FYI: The current search feature on that page searches within every SE site for questions/answers related to your search term.  There is a search feature on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) that finds active SE sites (from among all proposals).

Comment: @BilltheLizard, yes, the Area 51 search did work, but I would think we could have that functionality on the SE site.

Comment: Yeah, I agree it would make sense to have it there too.  It seems natural to want to search for topics right there at the top of a big list of sites.

Comment: Additionally, being able to search communities directly, rather than specific questions inside, could be of great value to users like myself who understand the general community I want to ask, but am uncertain if such a specific community exists. For example, asking about environment variables for RStudio seems like a Superuser question to me, UNLESS a RStudio specific community exists.

Answer (score 3):

You can search sites by name/description from the navigation bar.

- Click the "All sites" button on the top-right of the navigation bar.
- Scroll down to "*More Stack Exchange Communities*"
- Enter your search term

[image: Searching sites for "game"]

Comment: This of course works, but if I already know a community I want to ask a question in, but am not certain that community exists on StackExchange, or if it is a subset of a different community, the search you describe is not that useful. For example, searching on RStudio gives results on Mathematics, Ubuntu, a Russian version, Unix & Linux, Academia, Superuser, etc.