# Apple.stack is not listed on stackexchange.com

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, site-name

I was looking for the appropriate place to post my iPhone question, so presumably I was looking for something like apple/ios.stack. I didn't find it in the list of sites, I posted my question to superuser, and guess what: a moderator moved it to apple.stack. Am I just blind or do some sites not show up on the list? What other sites might I be missing?

Also, a commenter on my question suggested me to post to stackexchange.com. I might be misinterpreting him, but I wasn't aware you could post there. I thought it was more of a directory site.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176021/search-feature-for-sites-on-stackexchange-com (would probably prevent such confusion.)

Comment: And, in the footer "Ask Different" has the parenthetical "Apple" :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The site's address is [apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com), but its name is 'Ask Different':

[image]

This name has been chosen after Apple's ['Think Different'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_different) slogan: see [this question](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286/ask-different-really-surely-ask-apple) on Meta-Ask Different.

Comment: Well that isn't confusing at all

Comment: Wasn't aware of that slogan.  Guess that's why it was confusing, thanks

Comment: You can also type apple into the search box in the Stack Exchange dropdown or into the browser's find search on the full list to find this easily.

Comment: @user5948022 [worth reading](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286/ask-different-really-surely-ask-apple).

Answer (score 6):

As animuson mentioned in [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277921/apple-stack-is-not-listed-on-stackexchange-com#comment900289_277922), you can open the Stack Exchange multicollider/dropdown in the top left, and under "More Stack Exchange Communities" type the key word into the search box:

> [image]

This will also search the sites description, not only their name.

Comment: That should come in handy since it searches description too, thanks

Comment: Cheers, you can also use the browser's search when viewing the sites list, but having something built-in is usually better. :)

Comment: -1, no trademark/reserved symbol for the [Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66838/276705).